# Caching XHR get calls using Service Worker Toolbox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, service-worker, sw-toolbox

I am trying to store the results of the XHR get call the site is making so that if there is no internet connection I want the data to be retrieved from the cache/indexedDB . I am using [Sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) within my service worker. The URL i am accessing is 
"https://www.domain.in/field?searchparams=123" and I tried doing ,

```
toolbox.router.get('/field',function(request, values, options){
  console.log(request, values, options);
});
```

But I dont find any lead , Am I doing it wrong , ? Please help .

Comment: How are you registering the service worker?